# How much damage should be caused by falling into water?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, falling

I have tried to find the answer to this question by searching the books and was unable to find anything in the regular rules.

Attempting to search here only threw up similar questions relating to older versions of the game (1e) or pathfinder, so how does it work for 5e?

Is the damage negated by falling into water, if you were to fall from a great height, for example 800 ft? Or, is it reduced like resistance?

Comment: @Medix2 Hmm, fair point. It is at least a relevant related question.

Comment: What the answer turned out to be does not mean the question is not a duplicate. AS posted this Q also asks for what the rules say on the matter. If you have a specific houserule in mind, you could ask about the ramifications of that.

Comment: @Medix2 "Are there rules" implicitly contains "If yes, what are they". Would you think an answer simply stating "yes" to be sufficient? Also, the answer there says there are no such rules, in bold letters (and is right btw).

Answer (score 6):

## Falling is falling

The rules on [falling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Falling)(Basic Rules, Chapter 8) don't specify differences of what you land on.

> A fall from a great height is one of the most common hazards facing an adventurer. At the end of a fall, a creature takes 1d6 bludgeoning damage for every 10 feet it fell, to a maximum of 20d6. The creature lands prone, unless it avoids taking damage from the fall.

Falling into water is no different than falling on land with regard to the rules. I'm not a fan of bringing real world physics into answers, but water not being compressible along with surface tension make falling onto water from great heights still quite dangerous.

Comment: I'd argue that falling into water from 3 meters (10 feet) definetely isn't the same as falling on concrete from 3 meters, but going further into such a logic would make the ruling quite complex or even obnoxious. Thus, just for the sake of simplicity, "Falling is falling" is a good rule.

Comment: @StackLloyd It also brings up falling onto/into *every other medium* which is a nightmare that I will gladly leave up to individual GM's.

Comment: Get above about 25 meters, and water isn't any softer than concrete.  I opened this question hoping to find something that made a high fall into water about as deadly as one onto solid ground.  +1

Comment: @Zeiss You're indeed right, going by what I said would mean to start considering _both_ the material of the point of impact _and_ the height of the fall and, as Medix2 said, that'd just become a nightmare.

Comment: @StackLloyd Much more reasonable for a DM to rule that a fall of 10m or less into soft material takes 1/2 damage, than to make a simple rule complex for the entire game.  I wouldn't want anything more complex than this, game-wide.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I like the house-rule that when you're jumping down intentionally or onto a softer surface (hay, snow, water, etc), you can roll to reduce the damage from a fall by your check result (generally Acrobatics or Athletics). You get advantage on the roll if both intentional and onto a soft surface. A monk can Slow Fall in lieu of that roll, which is almost always vastly better.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym For my own table, I'd give a Dex save for no damage under 20 feet on intentional drops, hard or soft (I've dropped that far without injury, albeit 45 years or so ago), then 1/2 dmg for soft surface *or* intentional up to 40 feet.  Above 50, all that will save you is a huge hit point total or a nearby friend with *feather fall*.

Comment: @NautArch What check are you referring to? I don't know of any check that *generally* allows you to not be prone after a fall.  There's a rule about making an acrobatics check to not fall down when jumping into difficult terrain, and "Falling" says you don't go prone if you don't take damage... are you talking about one of those?